# Variable loses reference inside nested loop

Tags: python, loops, scope

My variable `tag` loses its reference when enters the nested `for`:

```
file_with_all_tags = open("tags.txt", "r")
origem = open("origem.html", "r")

for tag in file_with_all_tags:

    final_file_name = "tag-" + tag + ".html"
    final_file = open(final_file_name, "w")

    for line in origem:
        if tag in line: # HERE THE VARIABLE 'TAG' IS EMPTY
            final_file.write(line)

    final_file.close()

origem.close()
file_with_all_tags.close()
```

Comment: No it doesn't. The only way you'd get an empty value inside the loop is if it was empty to start with. Please show some example input and output so we can see what is really going on; probably you have an empty line in your file.

Comment: But an empty line isn't empty - it'll have a linefeed. The only potentially empty line is the last one.

Comment: I'll bet that `print(final_file_name)` will produce `tag-.html`

Comment: `for line in origem:` only iterates over the file for the first iteration of `for tag in file_with_all_tags:`, after that the file reaches the end and doesn't do anything for any other value of `tag`, is that the issue you are experiencing?

Comment: What do you mean loses reference? You obviously shouldn't be getting a `NameError` so loses its reference is misleading here. If `tag == ""` that might be, as Daniel said, an empty line in the file. Create an `if` clause to catch that.

Comment: Problem solved! Actually my iteration over the file "origem.html" was getting exhausted. I had to move the `open()` and `close()` functions to inside the loop. Thanks guys!

Comment: @anquadros Please post that as your answer and 'accept' it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! Actually my iteration over the file "origem.html" was getting exhausted. I had to move the open() and close() functions to inside the loop. Thanks guys! Thanks @rrauenza!